# Compiled Objective C running in Web Application

Tags: iphone, web

It may a bit out of the Obvious question. The answer to which I know, It may not be done. 
But still:

I have a Web Application which runs in all Smart Phones. I need to use some native controls like accessing Contacts etc of an iPhone. Which cant be done using a WebApp.

Is it possible to simply compile the Objective C code and use it directly to run over an iPhone via Web.

`Permissions` Well we can always allow it to be taken from the user like the ones which browser prompts while running a java code[plugin].

Comment: If you know the answer, why ask...

Comment: @dragon112 Its a 'maybe'

Comment: This can not be done. You can go and check for Phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible if you want use browser (Safari). But if you will use UIWebView inside your app you can use device capabilities.